# JLabel adding images <identifier> expected?

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, identifier, imageicon

```
// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JLabel image1;
private javax.swing.JPanel mainPanel;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar menuBar;
private javax.swing.JProgressBar progressBar;
private javax.swing.JLabel statusAnimationLabel;
private javax.swing.JLabel statusMessageLabel;
private javax.swing.JPanel statusPanel;
private javax.swing.JLabel titleLabel;
// End of variables declaration

ImageIcon PC1 = new ImageIcon("http://www.blogcdn.com/www.engadget.com/media/2012/06/shazim-pirate-desk-case-mod.jpg");
image1.setIcon(PC1);
```

I'm getting an error with the line `"image1.setIcon(PC1);"` line. It tells me there's an `<identifier>` expected. Please help?

Comment: If the code doing `image1.setIcon(PC1);` isn't in a method, then you'll see this error.

Comment: Basically what I want is to be able to start the program, see an image right off the bat, and then as you progress through the program, the image changes. How would this work in a method? I'm new to programming btw

Comment: BTW - please look over the preview of a question (below the message posting form) before submitting it!  The `<>` characters need to be code formatted or the entire expression disappears!

Comment: At a wild guess, generated code from netbeans, if you go to the constructor of the class there should be a line reading `initComponents();`. Put your two lines in that method and it wrap the URL of the `.png` file with a `new java.net.URL()`, as otherwise it won't be able to find the file (assuming it downloads over the internet as you seem to expect). You need to read some java tutorials, and understand at least the layout of the java code you're using

Answer (score 0):

You're not initializing the image1 object.